# How to pause camera preview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I am using Flutter's camera plugin to get a live camera preview. But I want to  freeze `CameraPreview` when the user taps the button. So that the picture will stay on the screen when the user taps on the button.

For example in Android: `camera.stopPreview();`

I cannot use `stopImageStream()` because I am not streaming the image.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A way this is accomplished is by establishing a counter and incrementing it, and pausing the `camera` controller when the pauseCamera value is odd.

```
var pauseCamera = 0;
CameraController? camera; //From the camera package.
...
FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            pauseCamera++;
            pauseCamera.isOdd
                ? camera!.pausePreview()
                : camera!.resumePreview();
          },
          child: CameraView(),
        ),
```